# Getting issues in Extjs4.1

Tags: extjs4.1

I have created a chartSeriesStoreModel.. But still the following error is thrown in ext js 4.1

Ext.Loader is not enabled, so dependencies cannot be resolved dynamically. Missing required class: chartSeriesStoreModel

Answer (score 0):

First, this you remember to enable the loader by putting this in your app.js file just before your application declaration?

```
Ext.onReady(function() {
    Ext.Loader.setConfig({ enabled:true});
});
```

Then, is your model included in the models of either your app or that of a controller?